# Searching php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a PHP array question regarding searching which I'm hoping some kind person can help me with...

The array shown below is an collection of arrays, e.g. order items. As I loop a separate array of orderIds I would like to return the appropriate array of products.

For example, if I request an orderId of 98305 it would return the arrays with the indexes of 2 & 3.

Are there any PHP functions to do this? I could loop each array and check the value and break out when it matches, but I feel this brings quite an overhead of performing multiple loops per orderId lookup.

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
     (
        [orderId] => 98303
        [product] => Product A
     )

     [1] => Array
     (
        [orderId] => 98304
        [product] => Product B
     )

     [2] => Array
     (
        [orderId] => 98305
        [product] => Product C
     )

     [3] => Array
     (
        [orderId] => 98305
        [product] => Product D
     )

     [4] => Array
     (
        [orderId] => 98306
        [product] => Product A
     )

     [5] => Array
     (
        [orderId] => 98306
        [product] => Product B
     )
 )
```

Any help appreciated.

D

Comment: I dont know such function. May be it exists. But if your orderId is unique you can use it as a key in array. Then to use isset.

Comment: That array is very small, I won't care about speed actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter)

```
$output = array_filter($input,function($a) {
    return $a['orderId'] == 98305;
});
```

Replace `98305` with the desired ID.

Comment: Good reason to be using it then ;)